# SQL NOT EXISTS error Return all people at least as old

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query that returns all the people that are at least as old as everyone. 
I have been given one table:

Persons(id, name, address, age, eyecolor, gender)

This is the code that I have written:

```
select name 
from Persons
where name NOT EXISTS (select P1.name from Persons P1, Persons P2 where P1.age < P2.age)
```

However this gives the a syntax error which says that the right syntax is not used near NOT EXISTS. I was wondering if anyone could explain what exactly is wrong and what I could do in order to get the result that I need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the persons with the max age:

```
select age
from persons
where age = (select max(age) from persons)
```

If you want to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select p.name 
from Persons p
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Persons P1 where P1.age > P.age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh?  I would think something like:

```
select p.name
from persons p
where p.age >= all (select p2.age from persons p2);
```

Comment: That could work but unfortunately I have to use NOT EXISTS